# apache pig get first occurrence of column

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table where I am pulling a customer base. I have a group id and just want only one of the customers in the group. The group id is numeric, the customer name is character. This is my first time writing pig scripts. All I can find that might address this is grouping, but it appears that to use any of the functions, the column needs to be numeric. I just want one of the customers and I don't care which one. So far I have something like this:

`cust_data = LOAD 'db.cust_base' USING [cloakhiveloader];`
`cust_all = FOREACH cust_data GENERATE group_id, cust_full_name;`

I've tried using group with flatten, or min, or even bottome, but I get errors on everything I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding,you want one customer for each group?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by group_id and use limit 1 to get 1 customer name for each group.

```
cust_data = LOAD 'db.cust_base' USING [cloakhiveloader]; 
cust_all = FOREACH cust_data GENERATE group_id, cust_full_name;
group_cust_all = GROUP cust_all by group_id;
one_cust_per_group = FOREACH group_cust_all {
                          first = limit cust_all 1;
                          GENERATE FLATTEN(group),first.cust_full_name;
                     }
DUMP one_cust_per_group;
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I would just add that in order to use the group_id for joining with the other table (which was why I needed this in the first place), I needed to add flatten(group) as group_id, first.cust_full_name as cust_full_name. Thank you so much for this.